# How do I extract "Hours" from a List and sort/print them in ascending order?

Tags: python-3.x

My question is "How do I extract ONLY "Hours" from this List and sort and print them in ascending order?

I have these lines(100+) in Network text file:

```
['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:16:24', '2012']
```

I got this far:

```
HMS = words[5].split()
```

My variable HMS holds the following

```
['22:16:24']
['22:03:18']
['10:22:18']
['05:44:31']
['05:15:11']
```

I want to extract Hours and its occurrences in the file and then sort and print in ascending order like this:

```
Hours  Occurrences
05     2 times
10     1 times
22     2 times
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension and [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) :

```
>>> HMS =[['22:16:24'],
... ['22:03:18'],
... ['10:22:18'],
... ['05:44:31'],
... ['05:15:11']]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c=Counter([t[0].split(':')[0] for t in HMS ])
Counter({'22': 2, '05': 2, '10': 1})
```

And for print in ascending mode you can use `sorted` function to sort your dictionary items :

```
>>> print 'Hours  Occurrences'+'\n'+'\n'.join('\t'.join((i,'{} times'.format(j))) for i,j in sorted(c.items()))
Hours  Occurrences
05      2 times
10      1 times
22      2 times
```

Comment: I always like your answers

Comment: Please look at this page where I have put a new request that shows what exactly I am looking for and help if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595244/how-do-i-optimize-python-code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a counter to count the occurrences:

```
lines = [
    ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '10:10:24', '2012'],
    ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:16:24', '2012'],
    ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '10:16:24', '2012']
]
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(line[5].split(":")[0] for line in lines)
print("Hours\tOccurrences")
print("\n".join( "%s\t%d times" % item for item in sorted(c.items())))
```

Result:

```
Hours   Occurrences
10  2 times
22  1 times
```

The `c = Counter(line[5].split(":")[0] for line in lines)` takes from each line the fifth element, it splits it using the `:`, takes the hour part and pass it to counter.

With `"%s\t%d times" % item for item in sorted(c.items())` we create the strings we want by taking the hours and frequencies stored in the counter, after we sort by hours.

With `"\n".join(...)` we join all these strings with new lines.

Comment: Both in one time and same ;)

Comment: You explanation is excellent. However, please look at this page where I have put a new request that shows what exactly I am looking for and help if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595244/how-do-i-optimize-python-code

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
data = [['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:16:24', '2012'],
 ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '23:16:24', '2012'],
 ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '21:16:24', '2012'],
 ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:02:24', '2012']
]

hour_frequency_list = {}

for temp in data:
  hour = temp[5].split(":")[0]
  if hour in hour_frequency_list:
     hour_frequency_list[hour] += 1
  else:
     hour_frequency_list[hour] = 1

print (hour_frequency_list)  # this can be changed to any format you need eg: display as a table columns or key value pairs
```

**Output**

```
{'21': 1,   '22': 2,   '23': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It worked except that I wan to see out put like this: - Instead of { '21': 1, '22': 2, '23': 1} --> I want to see 21 space 1 followed by in the next line 22 space  2  in the next line 23 space 1 and so on. It means no curly braces { } no ' ' , no : in the output as shown in the thread above. I guess, what data structure program section needs to be changed?

Comment: Please look at this page where I have put a new request that shows what exactly I am looking for and help if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595244/how-do-i-optimize-python-code

Comment: you can use sorted_list = sorted(hour_frequency_list.items()) . I have updated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29595244/how-do-i-optimize-python-code with the complete code.