# How do I optimize Python Code?

Tags: python-3.x

****Input****
['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:16:24', '2012']

****Program****

```
words =[]
HMS =[]
hour_freq_list = {}

for line in fHand:  # 1st loop
    line = line.strip()
    if not line.startswith ('From '):continue
    words = line.split()
    HMS = words[5].split()
    Hr, Mi, Se = HMS[0].split(":")

    if Hr in hour_freq_list:
            hour_freq_list[Hr] += 1
    else:
            hour_freq_list[Hr] = 1
print (hour_freq_list)
```

**Current Output**

```
{'19': 1, '04': 3, '14': 1, '11': 6, '18': 1, '09': 2, '17': 2, '15': 2, '10': 3
, '06': 1, '16': 4, '07': 1}
```

**Desired output**

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

How do I optimize my code to get the desired output in SORTED Order line by line? What data structure do I need to change to make it better and compact code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data = [['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:16:24', '2012'],
     ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '23:16:24', '2012'],
     ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '21:16:24', '2012'],
     ['From', 'john@hotmail.com', 'Fri', 'Jan', '14', '22:02:24', '2012']
    ]

hour_frequency_list = {}

for temp in data:
  hour = temp[5].split(":")[0]
  if hour in hour_frequency_list:
     hour_frequency_list[hour] += 1
  else:
     hour_frequency_list[hour] = 1

sorted_list = sorted(hour_frequency_list.items())

print ("hour | Occurences")
for k in sorted_list:
    print (k[0] + "    |" + str(k[1]) )
```

Output

```
hour  | Occurences
21    |1
22    |2
23    |1
```

Comment: I had extended your code like this--> d= hour_freq_list
for k, v in sorted(d.items()):
print(k, v)  but somehow my system didn't like sorted() function so I made another request to you. Now it worked, a million THANKS. You are the best. I am kind of new to Python so may I request to provide a list of good sites, books that might help. How would you layout Python journey from "Beginners to Mastery". You insight would be much appreciated. Have a nice day.

Comment: Well thanks, but I too am a beginner. The following article listed some great looking books. though I prefer the 'head first python' because its kind of like a story telling. Anyway good luck with the Python. (https://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2014/02/04/free-python-books/?relatedposts_hit=1&relatedposts_origin=184&relatedposts_position=2) and (https://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/07/31/10-python-blogs-worth-following/)

Comment: Thank you again for sharing this information. I much appreciated it. I am quite surprised that as a beginner you know a lot. Have a nice day.